# Processing two-dimensional dynamically allocated arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to find the maximum element from the elements below the side diagonal.
But my program searches for the maximum element in the entire array except for the side diagonal. How can I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int **a, tmp;
    int i, j, n;
    cout << "Enter size: " << endl;
    cin >> n;

    a = new int* [n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = new int[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << "Enter a[" << i << "][" << j << "]: ";
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }

    int max = a[1][n-2];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (i > (n - j - 1)) {
                if (a[i][j] > max)
                    max = a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "max = " << max << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            cout << a[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    _getch();
}
```

as I think it may be necessary to add an `if` loop to remove elements that lie above the side diagonal.

[image]

Comment: Try asking yourself a much simpler question: given some arbitrary row and column coordinates, `y`, and `x`, how do you calculate whether these coordinates are "below the side diagonal"? This should be a very simple logical calculation. And once you solve it, once you know whether a given coordinate is "below the side diagonal", then the rest of your programming task should be laughably simple.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an exercise in manual memory management or do you want to solve the problem you mention in the question? In case of the latter, use `std::vector<std::vector<int>> a(n, std::vector<int>(n));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you initiate `max` with value `a[0][0]` which is above side diagonal, so there is a probability it is greater than the value you need.  You can correct this by initiating it was the first value below the side diagonal like this.

```
int max = a[1][n - 1];
```

You can also make the program run faster by changing the nested `for` loop and eliminating `if` inside it like this.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = n - i; j < n; j++)
        if (a[i][j] > max)
            max = a[i][j];
```

Comment: how can I ignore the center element in the side
diagonal
(photo of the error I added above)

Comment: I edited my answer, it should be `n - 1`, not `n - 2`.